# What is the largest determinant you can get by filling in 0,1 or 2 into a 4-by-4 matrix?

Tags: matrices

For example

$$\left| \begin{array}{ccc}
2 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
2 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 1 & 2 \\
2 & 2 & 0 & 0 \end{array} \right|=40$$

Can it get bigger than that? And what's your approach?

Comment: Note you can take a factor $2^4=16$ out and work with 0 and 1.

Comment: I changed it into 0,1 or 2.

Comment: Relevant: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard's_inequality

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, the option of filling in a "1" can always be avoided because the determinant is always a linear function of any entry. So substituting either 2 or 0 can ensure an equal or bigger determinant.

And if the question is to fill in either 2 or 0, then as Mark Bennet pointed out, it can be simplify into a binary matrix. However, this "simplified" problem is actually a particular case of the very complicated "Hadamard's maximal determinant problem" ([MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HadamardsMaximumDeterminantProblem.html) | [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard%27s_maximal_determinant_problem)). The general solution still has not been discovered yet.

The answer for this particular case is $48=3\times2^4$. And there're 60 different possible matrices that have this determinant.

Answer (score 7):

More generally, consider an $n \times n$ matrix whose entries are in $[0,k]$ for some $k > 0$.
Since the determinant is an affine function of each matrix element, we may as well assume that each element is $0$ or $k$.  Moreover, by scaling, the answer will be $k^n$ times what we would get by replacing $k$ by $1$.  Now look up "Hadamard maximal determinant problem".
See e.g. https://oeis.org/A003432 and references there.

Answer (score 1):

$$\left| \begin{array}{ccc}
2&0  & 2 & 2 \\
2&2 & 0 & 2  \\
2&2 & 2 & 0  \\
0&2 & 2 & 2  \end{array} \right|=48$$

Comment: http://professorjava.weebly.com/matrix-determinant.html , this determinant does not equal to 48

Comment: Quite right! I was taking absolute values. I've corrected it.